# Yet Another diagram / modeling software suggestion request

Tags: uml, diagram

I'm currently looking for diagramming software that allows me to quickly map stuff and jot down concepts such as a filesystem directories represented by nested boxes containing icons (representing files.)

Off course the simplest solution of all would be to just use paper and pencil, but unfortunately i have such poor motor skills that after minutes i cannot even distinguish the shapes I've drawn myself, never mind have these notes be of any use to someone else in order to have him/her work with them.

So far I've tried a ton of software packages but none of it seem to be simple/flexible/powerful enough to help fulfill the modeling /sketching tasks I'm trying to achieve

Visio,
smartdraw
Edraw
conceptdraw
Vue
yEd
Dia
Kivio
paint.net
photoshop
Illustrator
GIMP

in addition I've played around with modeling tools including staruml,argouml and Visual Paradigm as well as Eclipse modeling, but most of them were too complicated, too constricting and in some ways completely alien. On a side note, I absolutely HATE eclipse, I'm used to writing shellscripts with nano on a shell, The sheer amount of features (That i will never ever have any use for) make it hard for me to find that which I'm really looking for. YAGNI G*DD*MM*T!

Allthough UML modeling is at times important, such models are more for the next follow up phase and would be overkill (as well as a creativity killing burden) when I'm trying to come up with something from scratch.

Right now I'm looking for something new, I would be more than happy if someone could perhaps suggest something,

Most importantly i would like to find a program where the software allows me to do add new shapes and with the parent shape automatically growing so that that added shapes all fit inside of it rather than that i have to manually resize the parent shape

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is a common one, and in recent years the big UML tool vendors have started adding functionality for sketching, as opposed to traditional modelling. My favourite, Enterprise Architect from Sparx Systems, has got "whiteboard" sketching and is also able to import from Visio.

It boils down to whether you know you'll just want to sketch, in which case you should get a tool which does that really really well (that last feature you mentioned is something I haven't seen in any UML tool). If on the other hand you know that you'll eventually want to turn the sketches into UML models, you need to consider whether you'll want to start over (which might be the easiest option, honestly) or have some sort of in-tool support to do that.

Answer (score 0):

For "UML as a Sketch" I use the Hruby UML Stencil for Visio. These do not enforce eny semantics, so you can be as sketchy as you need to quickly record ideas and communicate.

See http://www.softwarestencils.com/uml/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I use [Dia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dia_(software)). It is cross platform. Very simple tool.

However, My favorite has always been to sketch it on paper and scan (fotopragh it on my mobile) and keep it for records. Nothing beats pen and paper yet !

Answer (score 0):

I tried yEd recently, because I happened to see it mentioned in another thread here.  I'm quite impressed with it.  Its pretty easy to use.  I think the feature I liked the most is that I can draw my diagram regardless of the spacing and orientation.  Then 1 button and poof, the whole things rearranges into the ordering I want.

As a linux diagramming tool, im pretty impressed with it.

Answer (score 0):

this one is good for remote team members. 
Nothing to install
http://www.dabbleboard.com/

Comment: dabbleboard closed. too bad, it was an awesome tool. I wonder if it is still being used somewhere.  http://dabbleboard.wordpress.com/2012/08/17/dabbleboards-shutting-down/

Answer (score 0):

I've used Visio for so long IMHO nothing beats it.

That said, I rarely use Visio in meetings to take initial notes. We'll diagram on whiteboards (get someone else to do the diagramming while you "facilitate") and then I take pictures of the result. Transcribing the photos to a Visio diagram helps me think it through.